# stacking columns of pandas dataframe as rows in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am reading csv file with large number of rows and columns. The csv file looks like output of below code.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2016-11-24', '2016-11-25', '2016-11-26'], 
                   'us': [40000, 50000, 42000],
                   'uk':[30000, 70000, 82000]})
print(df)
```

#output

```
         date     us     uk
0  2016-11-24  40000  30000
1  2016-11-25  50000  70000
2  2016-11-26  42000  82000
```

However, I want to reframe the dataframe in the form given below:

```
df2 =pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2016-11-24', '2016-11-24', '2016-11-25','2016-11-25', '2016-11-26', '2016-11-26'], 
                   'country': ['us','us','us','uk','uk','uk'],
                   'value':[40000, 50000, 42000,30000, 70000, 82000]})
print(df2)
```

output2:

```
         date country  value
0  2016-11-24      us  40000
1  2016-11-24      us  50000
2  2016-11-25      us  42000
3  2016-11-25      uk  30000
4  2016-11-26      uk  70000
5  2016-11-26      uk  82000
```

Is there any better way to implement this? The actual dataframe shape is 42000x64.

Comment: they call this melting. it has [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) for the explainatiation. `df.melt(id_vars="date", var_name="country")`

Comment: I didnot know about melt. It worked.